# How can I improve MySQL Query to load result fast using JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

I am using following query to load results, I am fetching 10 records in each query,

but it takes more then 1 second to load only 10 records.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xXmi.png

how can I improve my query to load result faster.

```
SELECT S.session,
          S.session_timein,
          S.session_timeout,
          S.session_duration,
          S.session_groupsize,
          Date_format(S.session_createdate, '%d-%b-%Y') AS createdate,
          S.session_location,
          S.session_type,
          S.session_notes,
          P.payroll_amount,
          R.session_student_id,
          R.session_s_t_id,
          T.teacher_name,
          ST.student_name
   FROM   tbl_session_teacher_student AS R
          JOIN tbl_session AS S
            ON ( R.session = S.session )
          JOIN tbl_teacher_details AS T
            ON ( S.session_teacher_id = T.teacher_id )
          JOIN tbl_student_detail AS ST
            ON( R.session_student_id = ST.student_id )
          JOIN tbl_payroll AS P
            ON ( P.session = S.session )
   WHERE  session_agency_id = '54DB0A72-4F16-4BB5-A1FC-151B64D5817F'
          AND S.session_type != 'ABSENT'
   ORDER  BY T.teacher_name,
             S.session_createdate ASC
   LIMIT  0, 10
```

I also set indexes to all fields which i used in join. but it's not more useful.

Comment: you should use Index on where clauses.
make index on session_agency_id and session_type

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN  and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As you have already mention, applied `index` for all fields which you used in join. Requesting you to please apply index to column used in `where` if  text search, use `FULL TEXT INDEX`.

Comment: Maybe you need to do de-normalization if you have applied indexes already and also query is optimized.